# Entity Framework Migrations: Constructor of Configuration called always

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I created a simple console application, install EntityFramework from nuget and execute command Enable-Migrations.

Here is the code of main:

```
using(var ctx = new AppDbContext())
{
   var persons = ctx.Persons.ToList();
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is the code of the class Configuration

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<AppDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Configuration: Constructor");
    }

    protected override void Seed(AppDbContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Configuration: Seed");
    }
}
```

Here is the entity framework part in app.config:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

If I run the console application then the constructor of the Configuration class of Migrations is exectuted. Why? I don't change the database initializer.

> Update

I tried now some database initializers and look if the Configuration class constructor is called. Here my result:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    static AppDbContext()
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppDbContext>());
        // ==> Configuration class constructor called

        //Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AppDbContext>());
        // ==> Configuration class constructor called

        //Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppDbContext>());
        // ==> Configuration class constructor called

        Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(null);
        // ==> Configuration class constructor is NOT called
    }

    public IDbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

I set the database initializer explicitly, but the Configuration class constructor is called. Strange behaviour.

Comment: Do you have automatic migrations turned on? Are you getting an error? Might need to see your context class.

Comment: So you are saying you are not using Database.SetInitializers anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I don't set the database initializer, not in the app.config and not in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have executed the command Enable-Migrations. So what is does, adding a new Migration configuration class. This class will apply configuration changes specified in the class related to migrations when you run your application.

DatabaseInitializers are strategies to apply migrations even you haven't touched them still the object of Configuration class will be instantiated.

> Update:

If you're not doing it in your code then look at your application configuration file. That might have something that looks like:

```
    <contexts>
      <context type="AppDbContext, MyAssembly">
        <databaseInitializer 
type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[AppDbContext, MyAssembly], 
                             [Migrations.Configuration, MyAssembly]], EntityFramework" />  


</context>
```

For more details see this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

> Update 2:

I think I found the answer. When looked inside the EntityFramework code then it's clearly shown that the databaseInitializer gets fired when your first linq query is getting realized. See the call stack below captured while debugging your application.

[image: Screenshot of Callstack from with in the configuration constructor]

**Case 1:** When you're using `Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(null);` which actually create a `NullDatabaseInitializer<TContext>()` as default initializer which does nothing so Configuration was not called.

**Case 2:** When you remove the line `Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(null);` then things started using default values of providers. In this case there's no external specification of DatabaseInitializer is provided so EF will get the default Initializer which is `CreateIfNotExist<AppDbContext>` in this case.
The initializer then will try to find the configuration, and Ofcourse it has a configuration class so, the Configuration class will be be instantiated and constructor will be called.

Though it took me couple of hours to figure it out.

Comment: I didn't change the database initializer, so MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<..> is not used. But the constructor of the class Configuration is executed, but I don't understand why this constructor is called. Why this is necessary? If I add a second class Configuration2 then the constructors of Configuration and Configuration2 are not executed. Whats this logic?

Comment: See my updated answer. I have added details around what else could be responsible for Instantiating migration configuration.

Comment: Thx, but I don't change the config file. I don't set the initializer via config file. I tried now many different initializers. See original post the results... Very interesting.

Comment: Can you share a sample code where it can be reproduced? I would really wanna look what is going on there.

Comment: Its a really strange behaviour. Here you can download the code https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2856423/EfMigrationTest2.zip

Comment: It's working fine at my end without going to configuration constructor.

Comment: you see in the code that I set the database initializer to null. In this case, the constructor of Configuration class not called. But if you comment this line Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(null); then the constructor of Configuration class is called, although the default db initializer is used and not the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer.

Comment: @malt I figured it out.. See my updated answer. And I learned few new things too. ;) +1 for the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your effort. I also opened in the meantime an issue on github. There I also get some interesting answers in the last hours. Here is the link https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2327#issuecomment-109038601

Comment: Yup I already saw that when I finished posting the answer. I like the idea of having multiple configuration classes that you asked.